# .htaccess 301 Redirect Hash Tag Redirect

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect, hash

How do I do a .htaccess redirect that has a hash tag in it?

Example

Source:
domain.com/#/subdir

Target:
newdomain.com/whatever/something

Everything I've tried ignores the hash tag and either doesn't redirect at all, or redirects at the top level.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You CANNOT do that .. as hash tag is **client-side ONLY** and never sent to the server by browser.

Comment: How about via client-side JS?

Comment: Well .. I personally have not worked with this kind of client-side routing .. but you will need something like this: https://github.com/Ti-webdev/jquery.router or this https://github.com/wuyuntao/jquery-router. With this you will be able to implement navigations like here http://grooveshark.com/ or  http://prostopleer.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google's developer FAQ](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/faq) has this to say (I'm not really an AJAX guy, so this could be way off, if it is forgive me):-

> **Question: Can I use redirects to point the crawler at my static content?**
>
> Redirects are okay to use, as long as they eventually get you to a
>   page that's equivalent to what the user would see on the #! version of
>   the page. This may be more convenient for some webmasters than serving
>   up the content directly. If you choose this approach, please keep the
>   following in mind:
>
> 1. Compared to serving the content directly, using redirects will
>      result in extra traffic because the crawler has to follow redirects
>      to get the content. This will result in a somewhat higher number of
>      fetches/second in crawl activity.
> 2. Note that if you use a permanent (301) redirect, the url shown in
>      our search results will typically be the target of the redirect,
>      whereas if a temporary (302) redirect is used, we'll typically show
>      the #! url in search results.
> 3. Depending on how your site is set up, showing #! may produce a
>      better user experience, because the user will be taken straight into
>      the AJAX experience from the Google search results page. Clicking on
>      a static page will take them to the static content, and they may
>      experience avoidable extra page load time if the site later wants to
>      switch them to the AJAX experience.

There is also a pretty good discussion at StackOverflow ["Redirect 301 with hash part (anchor) #"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229203/redirect-301-with-hash-part-anchor), another at the [mod_rewrite forums](http://forum.modrewrite.com/viewtopic.php?t=3912), and another at [Webmaster World](http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4421184.htm) which might give you some pointers. I hope this helps.

Comment: This is correct, but it applies only to Google (and perhaps other search engines), not to normal browsers, and only to fragment identifiers ("hash tags") starting with an exclamation point (`!`), which Google treats in a special way. Also, the answer you quoted doesn't really make much sense out of context; you need to know how Google rewrites URLs containing such fragments before you can really apply it.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen indeed, this is why I linked to the dev FAQ and linked out to three other discussions on the same subject.

Answer (score 3):

As LazyOne notes [in the comments](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28722/htaccess-301-redirect-hash-tag-redirect#comment27598_28722), URL fragment identifiers ("hash tags") are not normally sent to the server in an HTTP request, so they cannot be redirected — or processed in any other way — on the server.

You *can* rewrite such URLs in JavaScript, if the user's browser supports it and has it enabled.  A very basic redirection script could look something like this:

```
if (window.location == 'http://www.example.com/page.html#foobar') {
    window.location = 'http://www.example.com/other.html#whatever';
}
```

Documentation for [the `window.location` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) can be found e.g. on MDN.

---

Unfortunately, this trick will generally not work for search engines, which only have very limited (if any) JavaScript support.  [As toomanyairmiles notes](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/28843), Google provides a special mechanism for [passing so-called "hash-bang" fragment strings to the server](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/).

The way it works is, essentially, that whenever Google's crawler encounters a URL with a fragment string beginning with an exclamation point (`!`), it rewrites the URL so that the fragment is mapped to a query parameter named `_escaped_fragment_` instead.  So, for example, the URL:

```
http://www.example.com/foobar.php#!this-is-a-fragment
```

would be rewritten by Googlebot into:

```
http://www.example.com/foobar.php?_escaped_fragment_=this-is-a-fragment
```

before it sends the request.  These query parameters *are* passed to the server, and so it's possible to process them on the server side, including in rewrite rules.  As [the FAQ answer quoted by toomanyairmiles](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/faq#redirects) says, if you return a normal 200 response or a temporary 302 redirect, Google will normally index the returned page under the original "hash-bang" URL, whereas if you return a 301 permanent redirect, they will index the page under the target URL of the redirect.

Just to be absolutely clear, all this applies *only* to fragment identifiers starting with an exclamation point.  All other fragments are still processed normally (and so not sent to the server) by Google.

Comment: +1 I was hoping an AJAXer could provide more information for the OP